# Subject loses observer from array after first value emission. Angular RouteReuseStrategy table-edit form communications

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router, subject-observer

My use-case is a list - detail view (master-detail, trying to move away from mastery termonology).

I edit a record from the table via routing to the edit form and passing the saved value between the routes/components via a data service using a subject.

The first edit of a record works, the second does not and my subject loses reference to my observer in the list component listening for the form/detail entrys' latest update. I am using Angular routing to cache the component instance and when the route is reattached I notice the observable stored still has reference to the subject. Yet after the first value is recieved the observer is lost on the source subject and any subsequent reattaching of the route/component the observer does not have reference to the subject<->Observable it using subscribing to via a service. I am using the service to act as push/bridge between the two routes. My solution for now is making the component do the subscription via the AfterViewChecked lifecycle but that seems expensive and I would like to find something more set and forget. The data service uses the Subject asObservable() method, when the first value is emitted. At the moment of emittion the listener/caller of asObservable receives the new value. On the second emittion/next value the subject lost the observer and therefore my subscriber/component can not recieve the value.

**My data service methods:
**

```
    private taskDetailViewSubject: Subject<Task> = new Subject<Task>();

    getTaskUpdated(): Observable<Task> {
      return this.taskDetailViewSubject.asObservable();
    }
    pushTaskUpdate(task: Task): void {
      this.taskDetailViewSubject.next(task);
    }
```

**My list/table components update rows based on form edits subscription calling getTaskUpdated():
**

```
    this.getUpdatedRows = this.taskTableService.getTaskUpdated().pipe(
      map((task: Task) => this.taskTableService.getTaskRow(task)),
      filter((task: TaskRow) => !!task),
      tap((newRow) => this.updateRow(newRow, null))
    );
    this.getUpdatedRows.subscribe();
```

**My detail entry/form component push method, on save we pass the new value via the pushUpdateMethod($event):
**

```
    pushUpdate($event: Task) {
      this.taskTableService.pushTaskUpdate($event);
    }
```

**My sleuthing screenshots
**
First edit and route reattached:
[Table component push update subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uzZT.png)
[Data service pushing update to observer in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqsjO.png)

Second edit and route reattached where subject loses observer reference:
*using console log to inspect the subscription since no value is emitted*
[Table component push update subscription - using console log to inspect the subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nbMJ.png)
[Data service pushing update to observer in table of second value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XeFM.png)

Any insight is greatly appreciated this issue bothers me greatly.

Somethings I tried before I put the subcription in the AfterViewChecked lifecycle which works but its a hack...
I tried not using asObservable() and returning the subject. I removed the takeUntil on the observer in the component. I put a console log where I put my fix instead so I could inspect the subscription of the observer.
I attempted a behavior subject but surprisingly no observer ever attaches, and no value is received by the component listening.
Unlike the subject the first edit fails to pass the value which is surprising.
[image: Table initialization and subscription does not add observer to behavior subject]

EDIT -----

I found that if I initialize the property in a declarative way inline not via lifecycle the subscriptions were not lost. I will be making a stackblitz to show this and poke holes in the issue I am seeing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try to use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`, so that the last emitted value gets cached and on (re-)subscription the subscriber will always receive the latest value.

So your **Service** could look something like this:

```
private taskDetailViewSubject: BehaviorSubject<Task> = new BehaviorSubject<Task>(null);

public taskDetailView$: Observable<Task> = this.taskDetailViewSubject.asObservable();

pushTaskUpdate(task: Task): void {
  this.taskDetailViewSubject.next(task);
}
```

For your **Component**, I would really recommend to add a mechanism that unsubscribes from the source-observable when the component gets destroyed (otherwise you risk annoying side-effects, such as your pipe getting executed multiple times in a row):

```
private unsubscribe = new Subject<void>(); // Will notify the pipes about unsubscribing

ngOnInit(): void {
  // I think here you could directly subscribe to the pipe?:
  this.taskTableService.taskDetailView$.pipe(
    map((task: Task) => this.taskTableService.getTaskRow(task)),
    filter((task: TaskRow) => !!task),
    tap((newRow) => this.updateRow(newRow, null)),
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe) // unsubscribes when this.unsubscribe.next() is called onDestroy
  )
  .subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe.next(); // unsubscribe when component gets destroyed
}
```

Comment: Thank you @kellermat for your input. I did try the behavior subject, yet ngOnInit will not be called on a reused route/component. It gives me weird behavior where it returns the last value and not the new value I sent, yet I still require the subscription in the AfterViewCheck which runs often. I do not see why the subject loses or the observer unsubscribes from the subject which is my main issue and resubscribing to the subject seems to do the trick without needing a behavior subject. I am going to go through the motions to make sure I am not a liar and will grab screenshots.

Comment: Gave it another shot, seems like it never passes a value or subscribes which is weird. I swear last time it passed a null value (the initial value). I have also read it should be a replay subject when you have no initial value.

Comment: I like your declarative style for the taskDetailView$

Comment: Could you maybe create a minimal example-app on stackblitz.com that produces the same weird effects that you describe in your question? I think your use-case is so complicated that I could only solve your issues if I see a running example and can debug myself ;-)

Comment: Just in case you create a minimal example on stackblitz and you wonder how to mock the API-calls. Instead of the API-Call you could return  `of(responseObject).pipe(delay(2000))`

Comment: Sure, I am doing this for work and have a work around so I will try and do that this weekend. I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Just post a comment when you have added your stackblitz-example, this way I will get a notification and won't miss it ;-).

Comment: "ngOnInit will not be called on a reused route/component" You can (should) use the `ActivatedRoute`for this. `this.route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(paramMap => { ... })`

Comment: I could not replicate the issue using primatives. I made a local project, working on getting a gitpod to showcase since I made it locally and stackblitz is a pain in the butt.

Comment: This is my failure to replicate the issue using very similar code.
https://stackblitz.com/github/straiforos/subscriber-lost-route-reuse?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: I'm not quite sure where the issue is. I noticed the comment in your stackblitz-example, yet your app is working fine even if I remove your declaration and just convert it to an ordinary `subscribe` inside `ngOnInit()`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yk3tvh?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fentity.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Btw: In your stackblitz example you used Angular 15. Is it the same version you are using in your own project as well?

Comment: @kellermat Good call no we are running 13, I will align versions later this evening.